# How to save each iterations xml request to one file and add a header and footer

Tags: jmeter, request, get, save, ctx

I am using Jmeter to create 100 records xml file. I will have 100 order id (unique) in this xml. I want a header and footer for this 100 order id like below:
header
Order1....
Order2...
Order3...
footer

But while running my script I'm getting like
header
Order1...
footer
header
Order2...
footer
header
Order3...
footer

I'm using a loop controller in my script and a ctx function in a Beanshell listener as attached. Can someone help me to understand what am I doing wrong

I tried using the ctx function .its helping to get the request. but each time header and footer get append with each order

Answer (score 0):

We cannot provide a comprehensive answer without seeing your at least partial (better full) response and your Beanshell code.

So far I can only provide the following recommendations:

1. If you're writing into the same .xml file with more than one thread it's better to use [Flexible File Writer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/top-ten-jmeter-plugins#writer)
2. [Since JMeter 3.1 it's recommended to use JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language for scripting](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) so consider migrating.